# perform click or focus in table row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

please consider this codes:

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="ArrowNav" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="height:302px;width:692px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th class="Id" scope="col">Id</th><th scope="col">"Group</th><th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">1</td><td align="center" valign="middle">1</td><td align="center" valign="middle">100</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">2</td><td align="center" valign="middle">1</td><td align="center" valign="middle">120</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">3</td><td align="center" valign="middle">1</td><td align="center" valign="middle">100</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">4</td><td align="center" valign="middle">2</td><td align="center" valign="middle">90</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">5</td><td align="center" valign="middle">2</td><td align="center" valign="middle">105</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">6</td><td align="center" valign="middle">3</td><td align="center" valign="middle">300</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">7</td><td align="center" valign="middle">4</td><td align="center" valign="middle">123</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">8</td><td align="center" valign="middle">4</td><td align="center" valign="middle">110</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">9</td><td align="center" valign="middle">5</td><td align="center" valign="middle">100</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">10</td><td align="center" valign="middle">5</td><td align="center" valign="middle">110</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I write a script for navigate between rows :

```
var SelectedRowIndex;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ArrowNav tr').first().css('background-color', 'yellow');
        //            $('.ArrowNav tr').first().focus();
        $('.ArrowNav tr:first').first().trigger('click');
        SelectedRow = 0;

        function ResetAllRowColor() {
            $('.ArrowNav tr').each(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
            });
        }

        $('.ArrowNav tr').on('keyup', function (e) {
            ResetAllRowColor();
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 40: //Down
                    SelectedRow++;
                    $('.ArrowNav tr').eq(SelectedRow).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                    break;
                case 38: //Up
                    SelectedRow--;
                    $('.ArrowNav tr').eq(SelectedRow).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                    break;
            }
        });

        $('.ArrowNav tr').on('click', function () {
            alert('a');
        });
    });
```

the problem is for navigating the table must have focus on it.I write this code for set focus: `$('.ArrowNav tr').first().focus();` but it didn't work.I also write this code : `$('.ArrowNav tr:first').first().trigger('click');` but click event on rows does not fire.I want in page load I can navigate between rows buy arrow keys. where is the problem?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8esyG/)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoping & Selecting issue.

Click event cannot be called before the click function has been defined.

```
$('.ArrowNav tr').on('click', function () {
    alert('a');
});
$('.ArrowNav tr').eq(0).click();
```

The `keys` event `up/down` cannot be bound to a table because a table cannot gain focus. The document starts with the focus right away, so you can bind the keyup/down event to it.

```
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    ResetAllRowColor();
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 40:
        //Down
        SelectedRow++;
        $('.ArrowNav tr').eq(SelectedRow).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        break;
    case 38:
        //Up
        SelectedRow--;
        $('.ArrowNav tr').eq(SelectedRow).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        break;
    }
});​
```

your working jsFiddle

Comment: I place that code under `$('.ArrowNav tr').on('click', function () {
` but in page load I can't navigate between rows by arrows without cclick.can you? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering the click before any event is set on it. You should move

```
$('.ArrowNav tr').first().trigger('click');
```

underneath

```
$('.ArrowNav tr').on('click', function () {
    alert('a');
});
```

**Then for the other problem** is that you can't put onkey* functions or focus functions on tabel rows/columns. You can only focus elements which accept input by user.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr tabindex="-1" onkeyup="alert(event);">
    <td>click me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`tabindex` should give the row focus.